# How to get previous or next item in list by date ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is one blog list. When I enter a blog detail page, I would like to show the previous and next blogs on the page in order of created date. How can I do this?

**Blog List**

```
_db.Blog.Include(p=>p.Sitemap).Where(p => p.Enabled == true).OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate)
```

**Previous and Next Blogs**

```
var previousBlog = blogsByDate.First(p=>p.CreatedDate < blog.CreatedDate);
var nextBlog = blogsByDate.First(p => p.CreatedDate > blog.CreatedDate);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var previousBlog = blogsByDate
    .Where(p=>p.CreatedDate < blog.CreatedDate)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var nextBlog = blogsByDate
    .Where(p => p.CreatedDate > blog.CreatedDate)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```